# What is the benefit of using <span> versus using <col> to display objects in grid like structures?

Tags: html

We seem to have favored grids creating `<col>` all over. Why not just use `<span>`? Is there an inherit benefit other than the repeatability with `<row>`? It seems like we are using it even to make 2 halves of a page.

Both, but `<span>` seemed much more difficult to use, and was not taking CSS as well as I hoped it would.

Comment: Could you give an example? Because `<col>` is a way to define a column inside a table and shouldn't be used outside the context of tables.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<span>` is a generic inline container wich has no semantic meaning and is normally just used for styling.
*Here‘s a guide for [span](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/span).*

`<col>` on the other side is used to define a column in a table and semantics on all cells. It should not be used outside of a `<table>` element.
*Here‘s a guide for [col](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/col).*

`<row>` is not a valid html element?! There‘s `<tr>`, wich defines a row in a table and should also only be used in a `<table>` element, but `<row>` doesn’t exist. *Here‘s a guide for [tr](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/tr).*

Overall, you don’t use `<col>` and `<tr>` for anything other than tables and `<span>` for everything else. I would say, it’s a very easy element to use, because you don’t need to add required attributes or anything and it has no semantic meaning.

You wrote in your post, that you want to create grid (-like) structures. For anything like this, just use a `<div>` container and the css property `display: grid;`. A guide to grid can be found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout).